# SQL Query Support

Tags: sql

I have a transaction table, i want to extract those transactions from the table whose time difference is of 2 hours and transactions are performed in 2 different countries.
I have written the following query but the problem is that it is fetching those transactions as well whose countries are same.

Query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.* 
FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE b, TRANSACTION_TABLE a
WHERE 
    b.CARD IN (SELECT b.CARD 
                FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE b, TRANSACTION_TABLE a
                WHERE b.TYPE_TXN IN ('21') 
                    AND b.RESPONSE_TXN='00'
                    AND b.DATETIME_TXN BETWEEN DATEADD(hh,-2,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
                    AND b.CARD=a.CARD
                    AND b.COUNTRY<>a.COUNTRY
                GROUP BY B.CARD
                   HAVING COUNT(B.CARD)>1 )
    AND b.TYPE_TXN in ('21') 
    AND b.RESPONSE_TXN='00'
    AND b.DATETIME_TXN BETWEEN DDATEADD(hh,-2,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    AND b.CARD=a.CARD
    AND b.COUNTRY<>a.COUNTRY
```

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, is `DATETME_TXN` (which is a terrible name, really) an _absolute_ timestamp, or is it _relative_ and will require conversion? See [this blog post]( http://www.sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx) for problems using inclusive upper bounds with contiguous types (such as timestamps). Should 'RESPONSE_TXN' be 'null' instead of an apparent (non-datetime!) placeholder value?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you should put something like that:

```
select A.*
  from Transaction_Table A,
       Transaction_Table B
 where -- both transaction should have the same CARD
       (A.Card = B.Card) and
       -- ... But different countries
       -- In order to prevent duplicates > instead of <> 
       (A.Country > B.Country) and
       -- Time difference btw A and B should be less than 2 hours
       -- NB! DMBS dependent! (Oracle version implemented)
       ((Abs(A.DateTime_Txn - B.DateTime_Txn) < 2 / 24) and
       -- Other transaction filters
       (A.Type_TXN in ('21')) and
       (B.Type_TXN in ('21')) and
       (A.Response_TXN = '00') and
       (B.Response_TXN = '00')
```

Comment: As an aside there is no point in using `IN` for a single value (I know that came from the OP, but worth mentioning anyway).